# How to work out complicated forms in probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume a population of $10^9$ people, tracked over a 1000 days. A person stays in a hotel for a probability of 1% in any given day. Each hotel hosts  100 people at a time.

How many pairs of people would've stayed at least twice together in the same hotel?

Comment: The information in this question appears to be incomplete.  How many hotels are there?  Are the hotel stays independent?

Comment: @whuber: The no. hotels should also be calculated based on the above facts. Let me reframe: Each person spends 1% of their time (1000 days) in a hotel. How many hotels are required if the above holds?

Comment: This sounds like a division problem.  Could you explain your understanding of the "probability" in the question and how it might lead to anything other than the obvious answer given by arithmetic?